# Cómo puedo mostrar los diferentes nodos de un XML en C#

Tags: c#, xml

Estoy intentado mostrar los elementos de [este XML](https://pastebin.com/ingK1qnA):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<milista>
  <titulo>MI AGENDA PERSONAL</titulo>
  <personas>
    <persona>
      <nombre>JUAN</nombre>
      <apellido1>GARCíA</apellido1>
      <apellido2>MARTÍNEZ</apellido2>
      <telefono>656432312</telefono>
      <email>juangm@yahoo.es</email>
      <email>jgm@yahoo.es</email>
    </persona>
    <persona>
      <nombre>MARÍA</nombre>
      <apellido1>LÓPEZ</apellido1>
      <apellido2>MARTOS</apellido2>
      <telefono>968553423</telefono>
      <telefono>670654133</telefono>
      <email>marialm@yahoo.es</email>
      <email>mary25@yahoo.es</email>
    </persona>
  </personas>
</milista>
```

mediante el siguiente código en c#:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    object midocxml = null;
    midocxml.Load("milista.xml");

    XmlNodeList personas = midocxml.GetElementsByTagName("personas");
    XmlNodeList lista = ((XmlElement)personas[0]).GetElementsByTagName("persona");
    foreach (XmlElement nodo in lista)
        XmlNodeList nNombre = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("nombre");
    XmlNodeList nApellido1 = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("apellido1");
    XmlNodeList nApellido2 = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("apellido2");
    XmlNodeList nTelefono = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("telefono");
    XmlNodeList nEmail = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("email");

}
```

Que me genera:

> Error 'object' no contiene una definición para 'Load' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'Load' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'object'

Y no sé cuál es mi error ahora mismo ([aquí dejo el código C# completo](https://pastebin.com/HmTiyuuh) por si falta alguna directiva y no me he dado cuenta).

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? No nos pases un enlace a "el código C# completo" porque no vamos a depurar todo tu programa, por favor revisa como crear un [mcve].

Comment: Error 'object' no contiene una definición para 'Load' ni se encuentra ningún método de extensión 'Load' que acepte un primer argumento del tipo 'object' (¿falta alguna directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: midocxml lo declaras como de tipo object, el tipo object no tiene ninguna funcionalidad para lectura de xml.

Comment: @Trackless edité tu pregunta para: **1** eliminar las etiquetas visual-studio y openxml, que no tienen nada que ver con tu problema, **2** agregar el XML a tu pregunta, no como enlace a otro sitio, **3** agregar el error en tu pregunta, no como comentario y **4** presentarlo bien formateado e indentado... Por favor revisá lo que modifiqué, que te puede servir para otras preguntas en el futuro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar, hay que declarar la variable. Si la vas a utilizar en todo el documento la puedes hacer global, aunque las varaibles globales no suelen ser una buena opción. La puedes inicializar tal que:

```
// Definimos la variable global dentro de la clase donde almacenaremos nuestro documento XML
XmlDocument midocxml = new XmlDocument();
```

Una vez hecho, debes abrir el documento dentro de la variable creada:

```
// Cargamos el documento
midocxml.Load(@"./MI_RUTA/MI_XML.xml");
```

Y, para finalizar, debes cargar los nodos que quieras. En tu caso, por lo que veo, buscas cargar los nodos dentro del nodo `personas` por lo que:

```
// Guardamos los nodos hijos de personas (que se llaman persona) en la variable 'nodosPersona'
XmlNodeList nodosPersona = midocxml.GetElementsByTagName("persona");

// Recorremos el nodo personas
foreach (XmlElement nodoPersona in nodosPersona)
{
    // Recorremos todos los nodos nombre hijos de la persona y mostramos su contenido
    foreach (XmlElement nodoNombre in nodoPersona.GetElementsByTagName("nombre"))
        MessageBox.Show(nodoNombre.InnerText.ToString());
     // Recorremos todos los nodos apellido1 hijos de la persona y mostramos su contenido
    foreach (XmlElement nodoApellido1 in nodoPersona.GetElementsByTagName("apellido1"))
        MessageBox.Show(nodoApellido1.InnerText.ToString());
    // Recorremos todos los nodos apellido2 hijos de la persona y mostramos su contenido
    foreach (XmlElement nodoApellido2 in nodoPersona.GetElementsByTagName("apellido2"))
        MessageBox.Show(nodoApellido2.InnerText.ToString());
    // Recorremos todos los nodos telefono hijos de la persona y mostramos su contenido
    foreach (XmlElement nodoTelefono in nodoPersona.GetElementsByTagName("telefono"))
        MessageBox.Show(nodoTelefono.InnerText.ToString());
    // Recorremos todos los nodos email hijos de la persona y mostramos su contenido
    foreach (XmlElement nodoEmail in nodoPersona.GetElementsByTagName("email"))
        MessageBox.Show(nodoEmail.InnerText.ToString());
}
```

El código anterior muestra el contenido de cada nodo dentro de cada persona, por lo que podrás trabajar con ellos cómodamente.

Answer (score 1):

Por partes:

```
XmlDocument XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
```

Nunca deberías llamar a una instancia igual que la clase a la que pertenece, ya que es confuso y puede llevarte a errores. Es mejor que uses otro nombre, como bien haces con `midocxml`.

```
object midocxml = null;
midocxml.Load("milista.xml");
```

Defines `midocxml` como tipo `object`. Obviamente, `object` no posee ningún método que permita leer archivos xml. Con lo que esa parte de tu código debería ser como el siguiente:

```
XmlDocument midocxml = new XmlDocument();
midocxml.Load("milista.xml");
```